CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing. Status code: 404 (fastify-oauth2 + react)
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource a github oauth api using fastify-oauth2 from react
Giving the error below:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Foauth2%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=user&state=<state>. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.
fastify-oauth2 config options:
const oAuthOptions: FastifyOAuth2Options = {
  name: "githubOAuth2",
  scope: ["user"],
  credentials: {
    client: {
      id: "<CLIENT_ID>",
      secret: "<CLIENT_SECRET",
    },
    auth: oAuth2Plugin.GITHUB_CONFIGURATION,
  },
  startRedirectPath: "/oauth2/github/login",
  callbackUri: "http://localhost:4000/oauth2/github/callback",  
};

callback route:
app.get(
    "/github/callback",
    async (req: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
      try {
        const { token } =
          await app.githubOAuth2.getAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCodeFlow(req);
       
        console.log({ userAuthToken }, "Authenticated successfully!");
        reply.send({ token });
      } catch (error) {
        reply.code(500).send("Failed to authenticate");
      }
    }
  );

cors config options: tried multiple options
const corsOptions: FastifyCorsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  // ["https://github.com", "http://localhost:5173"],
  credentials: true,
  // allowedHeaders: [
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
  //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  //   "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
  // ],
};

React code to call the api:
const handleOAuth = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/oauth2/github/login");
    console.log(response.data);
    history("/user");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

when I am calling the api from the index.html srcipt window.location.assign its working as if its replacing the url and calling it.
But when calling from a react app using axios its showing cors error

You should include credentials in your axios request
here is how you might implement this:
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/oauth2/github/login", {
 withCredentials: true
});

See if it helps !
By the way does anyone knows why @fastify/cors is not setting session-cookie in my case:

I am using local and google auth with fastify
session-cookie works as expected for local auth but not for the google auth

